# Using conversational action for use cases related to smart home, when smart home action does not have the required device type

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I want my smart device to be controlled by Google assistant. I have checked the smart home action guide, but the required device type is not available in smart home action.

I need to add customization to my voice commands as well, so smart home action is not option for my requiremnts.

Is conversational action a good choice to implement smart home. The [google action doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview#when_to_build) mentions the use cases for which conversational action can be used.
Smart home use cases seem to be not fitting in the above mentioned use cases, as it will take time to process the request.

Is there any other option to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

While selecting a device type to integrate with google, the device type trait provides many options for combinations for you to pick the closest device type you want with all the required traits.

> NOTE - Conversational actions are currently deprecated and will be fully shut down on June 13, 2023. For more information, visit https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset.